# Running flutter app in real iOS device [Windows]

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, flutter-test

I've been searching similar questions but ended up with concerns regarding the actual deployment. I have no problems deploying ios version because I'm using codemagic.

My question here is if it is possible to perform `flutter run` if I connected an iphone? Like how I use my android device and have USB Debugging enabled.

There are cases that some functions work in android but doesn't in iphone. So if it possible to run my app in an iphone and debug it, I'll just buy an iphone instead of mac since my windows machine is very capable.

Comment: It's not possible to run flutter project for IOS on Windows, you need to have MacOS system.

Answer (score 2):

Technically you have to own a Mac to build iOS apps. You can use external service to do something similar to what you want though. You will never be able to plug your iPhone to your computer and update your app but you can build an app and install it on your iphone.

For example with Odevio. In this case you have to install Odevio from the website: https://www.odevio.com

Then [configure Odevio to work with your developer account](https://odevio-cli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/6_configure_app_store_connect.html).

Finally, you can build an IPA file in the build menu with an Ad Hoc build type and you can then install this IPA on your physical device.

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately you cannot do this because the one who builds the application for iOS is the Mac machine, not the Windows device. So, the problem here is not in connecting the mobile to Windows, but rather in the reliability of building iOS on Mac devices only.

Comment: That's very unfortunate. Thank you for the info

Comment: You *can* do this and this is technically possible, just Flutter doesn't bother. For example in .NET MAUI you can connect an iPhone to a Windows PC via iTunes, enable developer mode a voi-la, you can run the app on a local iPhone and even "hot-restart" when making changes.

I wish this was possible in Flutter :(